# Problem handling free groups in algebraic topology

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, normal-subgroups, fundamental-groups, free-groups

Trying to compute the fundamental group of a topological space $X$ I have come to the equality
$$\pi_{1}(X)\cong\frac{\ast_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{Z}}{G}$$
where $\ast$ means taking the free product ($n$ times) of the group $\mathbb{Z}$ and $G$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $\ast_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{Z}$ which contains the free group generated by the word $z_{1}z_{2}...z_{n}$ where each $z_{i}$ is the generator of a different $\mathbb{Z}$ of the product.

Now here is my problem:

It seems to me that this group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, and I don't know wether $\mathbb{Z}$ is normal in the product, so I don't know if $\mathbb{Z}\cong G$, and even if that is the case I have no clue as to what is the quotient.

Could you please help me out?

Comment: It seems like what you have described is the presentation $$\langle z_1,\dots, z_n\mid z_1z_2\dots z_n\rangle.$$

Comment: By the way, that's an *isomorphism*, not an *equality*.

Comment: True, it isn't $\mathbb{Z}$ that I should think of, but anyway I think the presentation is of no use to me if I can't check if the subgroup is normal, is there any way I can do that? (I don't really know anything about presentations so maybe I'm saying something silly and it's just implicit)

Comment: Partial answer:
If $G=\langle z_1\cdots z_n\rangle\leq \pi_1(X)$, I don't think it is normal as one can check $z_3(z_1\cdots z_n) z_3^{-1}$ is already not in $G$.
2. Haven't really look into this, but see if this is helpful https://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/math_reu/proceedings/REU_Proceedings/Proceedings2007/2007NK_RM_JW.pdf

Comment: The group $G$ is a normal subgroup, so it isn’t just the subgroup generated by $z_1\cdots z_n.$ That subgroup is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z.$ But $G$ is the subgroup generated by all conjugates of $z_1z_2\cdots z_n.$

Comment: By definition, $$\langle z_1,\dots, z_n\mid z_1z_2\dots z_n\rangle\cong (\ast_{i=1}^n\Bbb Z)/\langle\langle z_1z_2\dots z_n\rangle\rangle,$$ where $\langle\langle z_1z_2\dots z_n\rangle\rangle$ is the normal subgroup of $(\ast_{i=1}^n\Bbb Z)$ generated by $z_1z_2\dots z_n$.

Comment: The quotient gives you a free group on $n-1$ elements, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

$$\begin{align}
\langle z_1,z_2,\dots, z_n\mid z_1z_2\dots z_n\rangle &\cong \langle z_1,z_2,\dots, z_n\mid z_1=(z_2\dots z_n)^{-1}\rangle\\
&\cong\langle z_2,\dots, z_n\mid \rangle\tag{1}\\
&\cong\ast_{i=1}^{n-1}\Bbb Z,
\end{align}$$

where $(1)$ holds by a simple [Tietze transformation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations).